# How to replace characters automatically in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I need to make replacement of characters such "á" "é" "í" "ó" "ú" for "a" "e" "i" "o" "u" , and "-" "," "." for just a space (many of these at once).
Is there a macro or something that could do this in an entire worksheet (on a regular basis)?

Thanks for your help.

Regards.

Comment: To do this just on a worksheet, you will need to write VBA event code. If you want to make those changes for your entire Excel environment, you can use the `AutoCorrect Options`.

Comment: Where could I find such code? For dummies...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way

Select all your data (Ctrl + A)

Press Ctrl + H

Find what: á

Replace with: a

Replace all.

*The other symbols in the same way*

Comment: Thats what is currently being done, for each letter and symbol, each time....inefficient and time consuming....